# For Loop refusing to Loop; Works Perfectly Fine if Run Manually

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova, for-loop

Alright, so, hopefully this is a simple enough question. I'm sure that it has to be something simple and stupid that I am not doing right. I'm building an app to program my exercise routine into so I can keep track of it every week (and to learn app development using Cordova). Within the code, each time I come back to the exersetup screen I want to read the saved exercise file, parse it back to an array of objects, convert those objects back into exercise objects, then display them on the screen. I have a loop that is supposed to check each element of the array to process the information, then display, then repeat until it has done this for each element in the array. It works perfectly fine for the first item, then stops. If I manually run the loop multiple times, it functions perfectly. Not listed is the code for the function addRow(), which simply adds a row of formatted dropdown selectors for input, then increments rowNum to keep track of which row it is operating on. Any help you guys can offer is appreciated. If I need to submit more information I would be happy to do so. Here's the loop in question:

**EDIT: Fixed some things to the suggestions in the comments below. Code still functions the same. Works perfectly fine on first run through loop, then stops. If I continue to run the loop manually (declaring it over and over again in console) it works fine, but it will not, for some reason, run the "for" loop. I've also included the rest of the function that the for loop is nested in, in case that helps.**

```
function readRout() 
    {
        console.log("Reading routine...");
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', getFile, false);
        function getFile()
            {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) 
                    {
                        console.log("got main dir",dir);
                        dir.getFile("exerciseroutine.txt", {create:true}, function(file) 
                            {
                                console.log("got the file", file);
                                exerLog = file;
                                console.log(exerLog);
                            });
                    });
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', logOut,  false);
            }
        function logOut() 
            {
                setTimeout(readLog, 50);
            }
        function readLog()  
            {
                exerLog.file(function(file) 
                    {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function(e) 
                            {
                                console.log(this.result);
                                exerRoutine = JSON.parse(this.result);
                                //console.log(exerRoutine);
                                //console.log(exerRoutine[0]);
                                var looper = exerRoutine.length + 1;
                                for (var i=0; i<looper; i++)
                                    {
                                        console.log("Loop count is: " + i);
                                        console.log(looper);
                                        exerRoutine[i] = new exercise(exerRoutine[i].type, exerRoutine[i].name, exerRoutine[i].sets, exerRoutine[i].reps, exerRoutine[i].pace);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i]);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].description());
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].type);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].name);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].sets);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].reps);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine[i].pace);
                                        addRow();
                                        setTimeout(fillExer, 50);
                                        console.log(exerRoutine);           
                                    }
                                console.log(looper);

                            };
                        reader.readAsText(file);
                    }, fail);
            }
        function fillExer() 
            {
                var typeRow = "typeSel" + rowNum;
                console.log(typeRow);
                console.log(document.getElementById(typeRow));
                var nameRow = "nameSel" + rowNum;
                var setsRow = "setsSel" + rowNum;
                var repsRow = "repsSel" + rowNum;
                var paceRow = "paceSel" + rowNum;
                fillType(typeRow);
                setTimeout(fillName, 10, nameRow);
                fillSets(setsRow);
                fillReps(repsRow);
                fillPace(paceRow);
            }
            function fillType(typek)
                {
                    for (var k=0; k<document.getElementById(typek).options.length; k++)
                        {
                            //console.log(document.getElementById(typek).options.length);
                            console.log(exerRoutine[rowNum-1].type);
                            if(document.getElementById(typek).options[k].value == exerRoutine[rowNum-1].type)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById(typek).selectedIndex = k;
                                    //console.log(document.getElementById(typei).selectedIndex);
                                    var quer = "#" + typek;
                                    //console.log(query);
                                    var typeInput = document.querySelector(quer);
                                    //console.log(typeInput);
                                    TypeSelect(typeInput);
                                    return;
                                }
                        }
                }
            function fillName(namek) 
                {
                    for (var k=0; k<document.getElementById(namek).options.length; k++)
                        {
                            //console.log(document.getElementById(namek).options.length);
                            console.log(exerRoutine[rowNum-1].name);
                            if(document.getElementById(namek).options[k].value === exerRoutine[rowNum-1].name)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById(namek).selectedIndex = k;
                                    //console.log(document.getElementById(namei).selectedIndex);
                                    return;
                                }
                        }
                }
            function fillSets(setsk)
                {
                    for (var k=0; k<document.getElementById(setsk).options.length; k++)
                        {
                            console.log(exerRoutine[rowNum-1].sets);
                            if(document.getElementById(setsk).options[k].value === exerRoutine[rowNum-1].sets)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById(setsk).selectedIndex = k;
                                    //console.log(document.getElementById(setsk).selectedIndex);
                                    return;
                                }
                        }
                }
            function fillReps(repsk)
                {
                    for (var k=0; k<document.getElementById(repsk).options.length; k++)
                        {
                            console.log(exerRoutine[rowNum-1].reps);
                            if(document.getElementById(repsk).options[k].value === exerRoutine[rowNum-1].reps)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById(repsk).selectedIndex = k;
                                    //console.log(document.getElementById(repsi).selectedIndex);
                                    return;
                                }
                        }
                }
            function fillPace(pacek)
                {
                    for (var k=0; k<document.getElementById(pacek).options.length; k++)
                        {
                            console.log(exerRoutine[rowNum-1].pace);
                            if(document.getElementById(pacek).options[k].value === exerRoutine[rowNum-1].pace)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById(pacek).selectedIndex = k;
                                    //console.log(document.getElementById(pacek).selectedIndex);
                                    return;
                                }
                        }       
                }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code with reasonable indentation so it is legible in your question.

Comment: Why the extra `+` sign in this: `var looper = exerRoutine.length+ + 1;`?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the debug console?

Comment: why is a function declaration inside the for loop?

Comment: Are the functions nested in the `for` loop?!

Comment: Lots of undeclared loop indexes being used which is a recipe for disaster as they become implicit globals and can accidentally conflict with each other.  Not sure it is actually causing a problem here, but it is certainly a bad practice.

Comment: No errors in console. I'll try to fix the formatting when I get back to the house. Sorry about that. I just copied and pasted from the .js file. The extra + is a typo. I fixed it in the code and still get nothing, unfortunately. I'm  rookie at this, only started Javascript a couple months ago and I've been self taught forever. I will try pulling the function declarations out of the for loop in a bit to see if that helps. <_< I'll have to look up loop indexes (never used before) and I'll see if I can use that, too, to help sort this mess out.

Comment: Why are you looping until i == exerRoutine.length? That's obviously beyond bounds. `var` declares a variable that is locale to the current function, so it's bad practice to use it in a `for` loop. `var i` should be at the top of the function where it's used (ditto for `k` in the other loops). What is the goal of the `setTimeout` in the loop? Ditto with the `setTimeout` in `fillExer`? Your use of `rowNum` in function that are called out of flow is recipe for disaster. What makes you think the loop is actually not run? What are your logs?

Comment: exerRoutine.length comes up in console, and has a set bound, as it is defined outside of the scope of this function, and is assigned a value within the function. I did get the loop to work finally, though I never really figured out why it wasn't looping in the first place. The setTimeout are used to defer the function, but I'm realizing now that they aren't going to function the way I want them to. The variable rowNum is declared on the page global scope because it is used for several functions. Thanks for the input. It's helping me out a lot.